# Azure AD B2C from an Angular application and msal: Loading customized UI Html

Tags: angular, azure, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to login into the angular application using the Azure B2c. The signin page is customized and the images, css, ui html files  are stored in the blobstorage in the azure directory.

When the login button is clicked the page is not being loaded and the console error shown is: 
**zone.js:682 Unhandled Promise rejection: AADB2C90047: The resource 'https://storageblob.blob.core.windows.net/storageblobcontainer/ui.html' contains script errors preventing it from being loaded.**

Can somebody explain how this can resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you have followed the below Javascript guideline for customizing your AD B2C UI

Follow these guidelines when you customize the interface of your application using JavaScript:

- Don't bind a click event on `<a>` HTML elements.
- Don’t take a dependency on Azure AD B2C code or comments.
- Don't change the order or hierarchy of Azure AD B2C HTML elements. Use an Azure AD 
  B2C policy to control the order of the UI elements.
- You can call any RESTful service with these considerations:

  - You may need to set your RESTful service CORS to allow client-side HTTP calls.
  - Make sure your RESTful service is secure and uses only the HTTPS protocol.
  - Don't use JavaScript directly to call Azure AD B2C endpoints.
- You can embed your JavaScript or you can link to external JavaScript files. When using an external JavaScript file, make sure to use the absolute URL and not a relative URL.
- JavaScript frameworks:

  - Azure AD B2C uses a specific version of jQuery. Don’t include another version of jQuery. Using more than one version on the same page causes issues.
  - Using RequireJS isn't supported.
  - Most JavaScript frameworks are not supported by Azure AD B2C.
- Azure AD B2C settings can be read by calling window.SETTINGS, window.CONTENT objects, such as the current UI language. Don’t change the value of these objects.
- To customize the Azure AD B2C error message, use localization in a policy.
- If anything can be achieved by using a policy, generally it's the recommended way.

Otherwise it could cause issues. Also I am hoping that you have added wildcard "https" in CORS value.

Here is a article which speaks about the same issue.

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/18508

Hope it helps.